# jQuery.scrollTop() doesn't update while the scrollbar is moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm using jQuery.scrollTop() to get the position of a scroll bar. I'm trying to create an animation which will indicate to a user where they are  in a list of content. It's a list of names, and I want to have a big "Q" hovering over the list as the user scrolls over the Q's, etc.

It seems that scrollTop() gives accurate information only after I've stopped moving the scrollbar. It doesn't reflect the position while I'm actually moving the scrollbar.

Is domElement.scrollTop reliable across browsers? Why doesn't jquery.scrollTop update while the scrollbar is moving?

Comment: A quick test shows that in FireFox, domElem.scrollTop actually does update while I'm scrolling. Curious taht jQuery.scrollTop() doesn't. I wonder how this behaves on other browsers.

Comment: Ok, I was being stupid. Sorry folks. That jsfiddle thing is pretty slick. Next time, I will recreate my bug there first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nPqez/

This is the code used to make it work:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="test">
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
    <div>test</div>
</div>

<div id="message">
Current scroll position: 0
</div>​
```

**JS:**

```
$('#test').scroll(function() {
    $('#message').text("Current scroll position: " + $(this).scrollTop());
});​
```

**CSS:**

```
#test {
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid silver;
    border-radius:5px;
    overflow:scroll;
    margin-top:20px;
}​
```

Comment: Awesome. I was doing something stupid (updating my scroll position variable only after the user paused). So, duh, of course I'm not getting the behavior I exptected.

Answer (score 2):

Try attaching the `scroll()` event to the window and testing it from withing there.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        //$(window).scrollTop() is accurate and updated while scrolling
});
```

Here's a working demo of this: http://jsfiddle.net/LydQE/

Comment: Thanks Ender! It was a bug in my code, not jquery, as you've very nicely shown.